# Conditional Formatting to show cells with contents overflowing BOTTOM border

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, conditional-formatting

I have emails exported to excel and need a conditional formatting rule to highlight cells which have contents continuing below the bottom cell border (for example the cells marked red below:)

[image: Example cells with content overflowing beyond the bottom border]
I have searched but could only find

[Conditional Formatting when text overflows the cell](https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/conditional-formatting-when-text-overflows-the-cell.843123/) (formula is: =LEN(A1)>6, but this will not work for random texts such as emails, I guess if the lines could be counted that would have to be adjusted for each font, but wouldn't find overflows caused by manually adjusted row heights (row 8 in my screenshot). I'm really looking for the trigger which caused the problem in the question below!)

[Conditional Formatting to Border Overflow Text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46774034/conditional-formatting-to-border-overflow-text) (a formula which doesn't work where overflow text present - the trigger to this problem may be the answer to my one!??)

Answer (score -1):

*Trapping text overflow is possible using so many simple methods like DATA VALIDATION for length check, trapping number of characters in cell/cells.*

*I would like so suggest the fastest & efficient way, the VBA macro, checks whether TEXT WRAP is active or not, and applies formatting on range of cells.*

---

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
  Cells.WrapText = False
  Cells.MergeCells = False
End Sub
```

---

```
  Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim rngLimit As Range
    Set rngLimit = Range("A3:C10")
    
    Dim rng As Range
    
    For Each rng In Target
        
        If Not Intersect(rng, rngLimit) Is Nothing Then
         If Len(rng) > 15 Then
           If rng.WrapText = False Then
             If rng.MergeCells = False Then
               
                
             MsgBox "Text more than 15 characters...", vbCritical, "Text too long!"
             rng.Interior.Color = 3394611
             rng = Left(rng, 15)
        Else
            rng.Interior.Color = xlNone
            
             End If
           End If
         End If
        End If
     
    Next
End Sub
```

---

**How it works:**

- Either press **Alt+F11** or **R**ight Click sheet's TAB.
- Then hit **V**iew Code.

*Excel will open VB editor.*

- First **C**opy & **P**aste `Option Explicit`, then both codes.
- Press **Alt+Q** to return to the Sheet.
- Save the Workbook as **M**acro Enabled.

*As soon you type value in Range A3:C10, code will check the length, and if more than 15 characters, Word Wrap & Merge cell is OFF then, apply the cell format.*

**N.B.**

- You may adjust cell references, length's limit & cell's interior color as you need.

Comment: Thank you, what would be the code to highlight only cells with lines going beyond the BOTTOM, and not others?  Please see my screenshot, I have not asked how to highlight cells overflowing SIDEWAYS due to no word wrap. You can see my cells are wrapped BTW

Comment: What does your last comment mean?  If it is an answer can you put it in an answer that is understandable please. I have not edited the post.  I only clarified the title.  My original question was very clear and so was the screenshot.

Comment: you have now addressed the 2 links I posted which I said did NOT answer my question.  If you cannot answer my question, why have you posted an answer?